# XML parser cut string containing accent

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I try to parse a XML file, but when there is an accent (é,à,...) in my file, the php xml parser cut the string.

```
   function __construct(){
        $this->xml_parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8"); 
        xml_set_object (  $this->xml_parser, $this );
        xml_set_element_handler($this->xml_parser, "startTagArticle", "endTagArticle"); 
        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->xml_parser, "contentsArticle"); 
        }
```

If my file contains the following string : cccccékkkkkkéllllllll , it will be displayed as ékkkkkélllllll in my web browser, and I do not know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML>
        <TITRE>cccccékkkkkkéllllllll</TITRE>
        <RESUME>Ceci est le premieré article de blog et l'aut</RESUME>
        <CONTENT>Ceci l'aut est effectivement mon premier article de blog
        et c'est un test
        </CONTENT>
        <FILE_COMMENTS>com1.xml</FILE_COMMENTS>
        <VISIBLE>true</VISIBLE>
        <TAG>Cool</TAG>
        <TAG>article</TAG>
</XML>
```

Basic parse function :

```
  function startTagArticle($parser, $data){         switch ($data){             case "RESUME":
                    $this->articleSection = 1;
                    break;          case "CONTENT":
                    $this->articleSection = 2;
                    break;          case "FILE_COMMENTS":
                    $this->articleSection = 3;
                    break;          case "VISIBLE":
                    $this->articleSection = 4;
                        break;          case "TITRE":
                    $this->articleSection = 5;
                        break;          case "TAG":
                    $this->articleSection = 6;
                        break;          default:
                    $this->articleSection = 0;
                        break;      }   }


/** Do not work **/
function contentsArticle($parser, $data){ 
        if ($this->articleSection == 1){
            $this->resumeArticleCourant = $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 2){
            $this->contentArticleCourrant = $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 3){
            $this->fichier_comArticleCourant = $data;
            $this->comm = new commentaire();
            $this->comm->init($this->comm_rep.$data);
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 4){
            $this->visibleArticleCourant =  $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 5){
            $this->titreArticleCourant = $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 6){
            array_push($this->tag_array,$data);
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is if I use the following contentsArticle function where I have replaced the  = by .= , it works fine. Accents charactere seems to cut/stop the XML flow.

```
/** work **/
function contentsArticle($parser, $data){ 
        if ($this->articleSection == 1){
            $this->resumeArticleCourant .= $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 2){
            $this->contentArticleCourrant .= $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 3){
            $this->fichier_comArticleCourant = $data;
            $this->comm = new commentaire();
            $this->comm->init($this->comm_rep.$data);
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 4){
            $this->visibleArticleCourant =  $data;
    }
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 5){
            $this->titreArticleCourant .= $data;
        }
        if ($this->articleSection == 6){
            array_push($this->tag_array,$data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you send the proper headers to the browser?
For example: header( "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" ); If you "view source" in your browser, do you see the full string or the cut one? if you see the cut one, the problem is in the parsing, otherwise, it's probably an encoding problem.

Comment: If I open my XML file directly in a browser, I see the full string...so I guess, it's more a parsing problem.

Comment: Same behaviour, and solved with the same diagnosis. I've changed '=' to '.=' and the word isn't splitted. Don't know why anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
//add
xml_parser_set_option($xml_parser,XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1").

//and the encoding is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. It just replace the "é" character by �.

Comment: is your XML's encoding utf-8..?

Comment: I believe. But how to be sure of that ?

Comment: chceck for encoding="utf-8" as mentioned above in your xml file.. like <?xml version=".." encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: the first line of my xml file is now <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>